# Can you identify this PCB joystick/rocker switch

Tags: identification

I have this PCB. It is from an Audi seat lumbar adjustment switch. It is a 4 way joystick type. 8 pins, 2 for each direction.

There is an "LK" logo and no other identification that I can work out by googling the numbers.

It is about 26x26 square, 11mm deep. The joystick is 12mm long

12v I assume and a reasonable current due to driving motors

[image: photo of joystick switch on PCB]

Comment: It *probably* doesn't have to switch much current as it is likely to tell a computer (the body control module) that you want to move the seat, and the BCM will activate relays (or maybe transistors) to supply power to the motors. If the car has memory seats then that is definitely how it goes.

Comment: You are quite right for this specific example, it connects to a seat module which has relays. However on non memory seats, it connects to the motors directly. I imagine the switch is the same as the PCB has thick tracks (at least 5mm)